# Passing parameters to inclusion in Liquid for loop

Tags: jekyll

have trouble with passing

```
{% include /components/home-lastest-posts.html nb=8 %}
```

code in my template home-lastest-posts.html :

```
{% for post in site.posts offset:0 limit:{{ include.nb }} %}
```

do something

```
{% endfor %}
```

It's listing my posts blog but my param not working. What is wrong ?
have try nb="8" too but not working too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use : `{% for post in site.posts offset:0 limit:include.nb %}`.